# How to capture images from 2 webcams parallely using raspberry pi?

Tags: camera, pi-3, fswebcam

I am working on the following code:

```python
import os
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1280x960 image.jpg")
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video1 -r 1280x960 image2.jpg")
```

in above code, the processing like capturing image from cam1 then process that image and after that switch to second cam an capture image and save that image. this process take total time of 5 sec. 
I want to capture images from both camera at same time without any delay os less time delay like 1-2 seconds. is it possible? how can we solve this problem?

P.S. I am not using opencv and don't want to use opencv right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1280x960 image.jpg", shell=True);
p1 = subprocess.Popen("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1280x960 image2.jpg", shell=True);
p1.wait()
p2.wait()
```

The images will still not be acquired at exactly the same time, but you'll have somewhat better parallelism. There are lots of obvious, and some non-obvious, improvements of the code above, but it will get you started.

Threading won't buy you anything, as what you are doing is running a separate program in a separate process anyway. If `fswebcam` can output to `stdout` rather than a file, use pipes to read the output from python directly, rather than writing a file to the filesystem and reading from the filesystem. The documentation for `subprocess` gives lots of examples.

Comment: Thanks @JayEye ur solution is workin time reduce to 1 second of image capturing and both cameras taking photos at the same time Thank you Sir.

Comment: another satisfied customer :)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
import os
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1280x960 image.jpg")
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video1 -r 1280x960 image2.jpg")
```

Try

```python
import os
from time import sleep
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1280x960 image.jpg")
sleep(n)
#where n is sleep time in seconds
os.system("sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video1 -r 1280x960 image2.jpg")
sleep(n)
```

Theoretically this should speed it up to whatever time you set as n.

For a better option you should have it be multi-threaded so that you can have them happen at the same time with **no** delay if you'd like to try that i recommend you [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: thanks for the help @sir_ian maybe i should try multithreading.

Comment: can i use ffmpeg for this?

Comment: sleeping will only delay things, it will not cause them to run in parallel

Comment: @JayEye i know that it wont make them run in parallel but it will force a   sleep speed of n which should be better than the 5 seconds that he reported

Comment: no, it won't; `os.system()` will not return until the command has finished executing. All the sleep() call does is add delay.

Comment: thanks for help. the  program i uploaded first and the second that @sir_ian suggested me are working same. the time of capturing images by both cameras is still same i.e. 5 seconds. is there is any other solution please let me know or can we switch to opencv, i dont know much about opencv